# How do i structure an object array using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In an object i have a name, picture and position
How do I get the people with the same position and group them together in which the names corresponding to the position can be highlighted under it

For example a data from a json file

```
    {
    "aspirants" : [
    {
    "position": "President",
    "name": "John",
    "photo": "https://"
    },
    {
    "position": "President",
    "name": "Smith",
    "photo": "https://"
    },
    {
    "position": "secretary",
    "name": "Felicia",
    "photo": "https://"
    },
    {
    "position": "President",
    "name": "Jane",
    "photo": "https://"
    }
    ]
    }
```

To give something like this

**President**

John and (the person photo)

Smith and (the person photo)

**Secretary**

Felicia and (the person photo)

Jane and (the person photo)

Comment: Use `reduce` method of Array

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is probably to use the Array `reduce` method. You could make a function like this:

```js
function groupByKey(people, key) {
  return people.reduce((peopleSoFar, currentPerson) => {
    return {
      ...peopleSoFar,
      [currentPerson[key]]: [
        ...(peopleSoFar[currentPerson[key]] || []), currentPerson
      ]
    }
  }, {});
}
```

and then call it like this:

```js
groupByKey(data.aspirants, 'position')
```

and that would give you this:

```js
{
  President: [
    { position: 'President', name: 'John', photo: 'https://' },
    { position: 'President', name: 'Smith', photo: 'https://' },
    { position: 'President', name: 'Jane', photo: 'https://' }
  ],
  secretary: [ { position: 'secretary', name: 'Felicia', photo: 'https://' } ]
}
```

Comment: I got an error, it says: cannot read property of 'reduce' of undefined

Comment: In this example, it assumes you've assigned the entire contents of your JSON to `data`.